# HTML5 contenteditable attribute not working properly on iOS7 Mobile Safari

Tags: html, ipad, ios7, mobile-webkit

It seems that the contenteditable attribute (which worked fine on iOS6) has stopped working on iOS7 webkit. Though the browser seems to recognize the field as editable, and brings up the keyboard, any input seems to close it, or it fails to register. Any encounter the same problem, or have any workarounds?

You can try it out over here - http://html5demos.com/contenteditable

Thanks!

Comment: It’s still an issue in iOS 17, but below are the solutions.

Answer (score 38):

I ran into this problem today. The solution for me was to set **user-select** to "**text**" in the CSS for any editable elements:

```
* {
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

input,
textarea,
[contenteditable] {
    -webkit-user-select: text;
    user-select: text;
}
```

Comment: Confirmed this is still required for iOS 10, when setting the `user-select` property globally.

Comment: * Confirmed this is still required for iOS 10 in September of 2017 - No updates have changed this. Hopefully iOS 11 is different. Great find/fix @Jason P

Comment: I still needed to add -webkit-user-select: text on iOS 13.3

Answer (score 6):

I was having the same issue and the below link helped me resolve it.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariCSSRef/Articles/StandardCSSProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001266-SW1

The solution that worked for me was to set **"-webkit-user-modify"** property to **"read-write"** for any editable element (you have defined as contenteditable)

```
*{
    -webkit-user-modify:read-write;
}
```

Comment: Note [compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-modify#browser_compatibility) as well as the `read-write-plaintext-only` value, which prevents rich content pasting.