# html control/widget to inline edit a word or section in a paragraph

Tags: jquery, html, richedit, jquery-widgets

Is there a library or widget out there that allows inline editing of certain sections of a paragraph?  I have a mad lib like interface that have certain words highlighted.  The idea is to allow the user to click on these highlighted sections and then inline edit the words , even supporting an edit field to word wrap around to the next line.

Are there any pre-made widgets or libraries that do this?

Comment: [`contentEditable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_Editable), maybe?

Comment: It's simple enough with CSS and rendering elements in-line.  That's pretty much all you need.

Comment: unfortunately it behaves oddly on mobile web, the keyboard comes up but it doesn't seem to update the on screen text.

Comment: got it working with help from this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21295698/html5-contenteditable-attribute-not-working-properly-on-ios7-mobile-safari

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign `contentEditable` as an attribute to highlighted sections.

Comment: and looks like I have to set user-select: text in the css for it to work on mobile as well.

Answer (score 0):

[Jeditable](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable) matches your criteria perfectly I think. 
It allows you to define custom styles for what you want to be editable and various events that trigger the textbox to show up. [Check out the demo here!](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable/default.html)